# Strange behavior of UINavigationController with child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I need a draggable view over all of controllers in navigation controller's stack. For managing this view and gesture recognizer I use custom VC called ChildViewController. In viewDidLoad method of navController I add child controller. In ChildViewController I create view and set constraints in didMoveToParent method. Constraint's constant using in gesture recognizer to calculate position of view when panning. And its works. But every time when I push or pop controllers in navController's stack, navController calls didMoveToParent method of ChildViewController with constraints setup. After that gesture recognizer starts working not correctly. I solve this problem by implement isConstrainted variable and adding if statements in didMoveToParent. Now constraints setups once and all works great. But why navController call didMoveToParent of child vc when pushing or popping when I add child vc once in viewDidLoad? GIF https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEeu6.gif  Project on gitHub https://github.com/ayatsev/ChildNavController

```
class CustomNavController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let childController = ChildViewController()
        addChild(childController)
        view.addSubview(childController.view)
        childController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

}


class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

var xConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var yConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var isConstrainted = false


lazy var childView: UIView = {
    let cv = UIView()
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    cv.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
    cv.backgroundColor = .green
    return cv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view = childView 
}

override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    print("--- CHILD: Did Move To Parent")
    guard let parent = parent else {return}
    if !isConstrainted {
        childView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        childView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        xConstraint = childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40)
        xConstraint.isActive = true
        yConstraint = childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.topAnchor, constant: parent.view.frame.height * 2 / 3)
        yConstraint.isActive = true
        isConstrainted = true
    }
}

@objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let parent = parent else {return}
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: parent.view)

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .changed:
        xConstraint.constant += translation.x
        yConstraint.constant += translation.y
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: parent.view)
    default:
        break
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But why navController call didMoveToParent of child vc when pushing or popping

There's no point asking "why" about this. It's just how the system works. Sometimes `didMove(toParent:)` arrives without a corresponding `willMove(toParent:)`. Sometimes `didMove(toParent:)` arrives even though this view controller was previously the child of this parent and remains the child of this parent. It seems crazy, I know. But yours not to reason why, yours to code in such a way as to respond coherently to the messages that you get.

Comment: I believe my answer is wrong. I now believe that the reason you're getting `didMove(toParent:)` is because your implementation of `didMove(toParent:)` is wrong. It needs to start by calling `super`, i.e. it should `super.didMove(toParent:parent)`.